# road feedback through steering wheel

Tags: steering, land-rover, freelander

I have a Land Rover Freelander 2, 2008 model. A few months back it started having some issues with steering/handling on the road. When I drive on a smooth road all is good, but when there are any road bumps, the steering wheel jerks left/right and the whole car wants to steer in a direction towards the bump and can be very uncomfortable. 
Things done on the car:

- corrected tire pressure
- 4 wheel alignment and balance
- tried different set of wheels
- replaced lower control arms L+R
- replaced front suspension struts L+R (including bushings etc)
- replaced steering rack

Next on the list would be steering pump replacement.

I already spent a lot of money trying to fix it but the problem still persists, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the hub bearings?

Comment: Mike, the mechanic checked this out last time the car was in the garage. I am happy to have it checked out again, but before I do, I want to make a list of all possible causes, as this issue appears to be very unique.